# merge lite version, but report error 'Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView"'

Tags: ios, admob

The lite version of one of my app used admob.
Original lite version and full version work well.
I try to merge the lite version and full version in same project as different targets.
I use constant _lite to switch to lite version

//ConstDefine.h

```
#define _lite
```

ViewController1.h

```
#include "ConstDefine.h" 
#ifdef _lite

#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@class GADRequestError;
@class GADBannerView;

#endif
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <

 #ifdef _lite

GADBannerViewDelegate,

 #endif

..
>
#ifdef _lite

@property (nonatomic,retain)GADBannerView* admobView;

#endif



//...

}
```

ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

#ifdef _lite
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#endif

#ifdef _lite
@synthesize admobView;
#endif
```

I also added AdSupport.framework StoreKit.framework to lite version target.

but compile error reports:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController1.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked GoogleMobileAds.a, it has been add to target lite version.

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: That define should be in the *Build Settings* of the target; not in a source/header file.

Comment: Looks like same file is referenced more than once in buil phases -> compile sopurce files. Remove this files GADBannerView.h and GADRequest.h from compile resource and add reference again

Comment: @trojanfoe I think I have done, add new scheme and target for lite version

Comment: @Muhammad 'compile source files' have no .h file

Comment: remove admob framework from search path header and add again.

Comment: @arachide Well the code you show is misleading then.